# ASP.NET: How to apply CSS class for a Table generated in C# codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET page and I am generating an HTML table in my server side code (codebehind file )as follows.

```
 HtmlTable iTblCart = new HtmlTable();
 HtmlTableRow iRowHeader = new HtmlTableRow();
 HtmlTableCell iCellHead1 = new HtmlTableCell();
 iCellHead1.InnerText= "Item";
 iRowHeader.Cells.Add(iCellHead1);
 iTblCart.Rows.Add(iCartRow);
 pnlPhoneCart.Controls.Add(iTblCart);  //appending to a panel
```

I want to apply a CSS class to this table.I could not find such a property from the intellisense.Am i missing anything ? Can anyone guide me how to go ahead ?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Yes I got the answer.Here it is

```
iTblCart.Attributes.Add("Class", "clsTradeInCart");
```

and clsTradeInCart is my CSS class name